# Can I use Spring Expression Language in an "alias" definition?

Tags: spring

I am trying to create an alias in a spring context config like this:

```
<alias name="#{ ... code to lookup from config file ...}" alias="BeanName"/>
```

but it doesn't seem to execute the EL in the "name" attribute.  Is this not allowed?

Comment: Can you share the EL expression?

Comment: See Sotrios's answer, but I even tried a very simple expression like #{'BeanName'} and it wasn't converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it's not allowed, it's that there is no registered `BeanExpressionResolver` for aliases. You can use property placeholders `${}`, but that's a whole different component that handles it.

Comment: @Dave It would be weird. The lifecycle of aliases is not the same as the lifecycle of beans. You could possibly use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that uses some resolver to do it, but it would have to be done lazily at the time the beans are created. Can you explain why you need this? There might be better ways.

Comment: I am changing the implementation of some beans.  I'd like to be able to switch back with a config file change to the old version in case some issues are found.  So I wanted to define both versions of the beans:  beanOld and beanNew and then have an alias that points "bean" to either beanOld or beanNew based on config.  To further complicate we have a config system that it not based on property files and require calls to a static method to get values.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by defining in-line properties that make use of EL and then reference those in the alias via ${} notation.

Comment: @Dave Do you have a link where I can read about "in-line" properties? Never heard of them before but I want to do exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: @Huckle  Go to this page:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html .  Section 9.4.1 shows examples of using the EL in xml configuration.  Later sections show how to do this in Annotation based configuration as well.

Comment: @Dave Do you mind writing up an answer with a complete example. You've pointed me at the EL docs, but EL is not processed in the name attribute of an alias. Based on several comments here, Spring properties (${}) are processed in the name attribute, but how to get an arbitrary EL expression into a Spring property is not clear. The common way of defining Spring properties is via a properties file and/or a properties list passed into the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator`. Neither work in this case.